# I want to replace 'NA' values for year column in dataset in R

Tags: r

I want to replace 'NA' values for year column in dataset in R.

I have tried searching using mode, but, it's giving me mode as 'NA'

```
set.seed(1)

getmode <- function(x){
  Md <- unique(x)
  Md[which.max(tabulate(match(x, Md)))]
}

#below line is not replacing NA values by mode
trainset$GarageYrBlt[is.na(trainset$GarageYrBlt)] <- getmode(trainset$GarageYrBlt)


#because mode value is showing as NA
getmode(trainset$GarageYrBlt)
```

I can't use mean or median for the same.

Is there any method by which I can replace missing value for year with the relevent value of the year.

Comment: to compute mode:  `getmode<-function(x)as.numeric(names(which.max(table(x))))`. In this way, you will not get an `NA` value returned. But in your case, you will get `NA` value returned

Comment: Thanks mate...it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use **is.na** function and make replace value this month with  Sys.yearmon()

Sys.yearmon()  prints as follow -> 2019.5

Code line

Dataset$Col[is.na(Dataset$Column )] <- Sys.yearmon()